React Typescript HOC
I'm trying to implement HOC that will redirect a user to a specified path depending on whether he is authorized or not
import {Navigate} from "react-router-dom";
import {useAppSelector} from "../redux/redux-store";
import React from "react";

export const withAuthNavigate = <Props extends JSX.IntrinsicAttributes>(
    Component: React.ComponentType<Props>
) => (props: Props) => {
    const isAuth = useAppSelector(state => state.authReducer.isAuth)
    return isAuth ? <Component {...props}/> : <Navigate to="/login"/>
}

Target component file:
const mapStateToProps = (state: RootState) => {
    return {
        dialogs: state.dialogsReducer.dialogs,
        messages: state.dialogsReducer.messages
    }
}

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch: AppDispatch) => {
    return {
        sendMessage: (messageText: string) => {
            dispatch(sendMessage(messageText))
        }
    }
}

const authNavigateComponent = withAuthNavigate(Dialogs)

const DialogsContainer = connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(authNavigateComponent)

export default DialogsContainer;

Error:
`TS2345: Argument of type 'FC<DialogsProps>' is not assignable to
parameter of type 'ComponentType<IntrinsicAttributes>'. Type 
'FunctionComponent<DialogsProps>' is not assignable
 to type 'FunctionComponent<IntrinsicAttributes>'. Types of property 
'propTypes' are incompatible. Type 'WeakValidationMap<DialogsProps> | undefined' 
is not assignable to type 
'WeakValidationMap<IntrinsicAttributes> | undefined'. Type 
'WeakValidationMap<DialogsProps>' has no properties in common with 
type 'WeakValidationMap<IntrinsicAttributes>'.`

I don't really understand what props a child component should have.

you should make the title a proper question and more directed.

that being said you can look at this one for React Native TypeScript it may help you out https://github.com/trajano/expo-experiments/blob/master/packages/my-hooks/src/DoNothing.tsx

The problem was in the props passed to the target component Dialogs. It was like this:
type DialogsProps = {
    dialogs: Array<{id: number, name: string}>,
    messages: Array<{id: number, messageText: string}>,
    sendMessage: (messageText: string) => void
}

I changed it to the type used in the reducer:
type DialogType = {
    id: IdType,
    name: string
} type MessageType = {
    id: IdType,
    messageText: string
}
type DialogsProps = {
    dialogs: Array<DialogType>,
    messages: Array<MessageType>,
    sendMessage: (messageText: string) => void
}

Still don't fully understand the cause of the problem, but it's solved.
